# Filtering based on object type

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am consuming messages from a queue and after doing some processing, I need to route the messages to different services.

Queue -> service (activator) -> router

Currently I am using a chain containing service activator and payload based router. The problem is that the router lets to send to a channel only but I would want it to go another service.

Comment: I don't understand the question - simply subscribe the next service activator(s) to the router output channel(s).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement properly, You need to use `publish-subscribe-channel` instead of `router` after your `service-activator`.

**Queue -> service-activator -> publish-subscribe-channel-> Your services**

The example is here : [publish-subscribe-channel example](https://github.com/benjaminwootton/spring-integration-examples/blob/master/target/classes/publish-subscribe-channel-example.xml)